# how to get the width of the div and change it with class using extjs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, extjs

I need to get the width of the the div class named 'msg' based on the div id 'task123' and also change the width accordingly using `Ext.query` method function in extjs

> > ```
> > html code
> > <div id="task123">
> > <div class="msg" id="sample">
> > <ul class="msg-icons">Item 1</ul>
> > <h3>"welcome"</h3>
> > <div>Element</div>
> > </div>
> > </div>
> >     the ext js code follows:
> > ```
> >
> > get the width of the div.msg based on the div id task123.
> >        Ext js:
> >
> > ```
> > var el = Ext.fly(task123).query('div.msg',true);
> > var wh = (2 * (el[0].getWidth()));
> > el.setWidth(wh);
> > ```

it displays no property getWidth for the element. I think the problem on getting the index element.

Answer (score 2):

please try this its working for me :

```
var el =  Ext.get('sample');
var wh = (2 *(el.getWidth()));
el.setWidth(wh);
```

Comment: hi i use the above code by naresh. its works fine. i tried already in the format which you given. its not working wen i use two time of popup message open. anyway thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to get a single child:

```
var el = Ext.fly('task123').down('div.msg');
el.setWidth(el.getWidth() * 2);
```